# Grand Staff of Charming mission?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a Grand Staff of Charming that I cannot drop as it is part of a quest.

Does anyone know what quest it is for?

Answer (score 4):

It's for [Onmund's Request](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Onmund's_Request).

You are supposed to take the staff back to Enthir.

Comment: This quest often bugs if you already have the staff when you start it. The solution is to leave the staff on a weapon rack until after you get the quest, then go pick it up (if you actually need it -- the quest can be done without it).

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the glitch. Was able to get rid of it. Many thanks!